# Cannot present .xib viewcontroller over existing tableviewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I am using a PasscodeLock swift source code off of github in the journal function of my app. I am using the passcode to allow the user to lock the journal so people can't just open the app and read their entries.

The .xib file in my project is the actual passcode lock screen that is supposed to be presented. The PasscodeLockPresenter.swift file attached is the file that is in charge of presenting the view controller over the existing window and presenting the lock screen. Touch ID is also enabled for the lock screen. When I go into the screen on the app that the lock screen is supposed to be presented, the prompt for Touch ID comes up, but no lock screen view controller. How do I go about fixing this? Is it just a segue error?

**PasscodeLockPresenter.swift**

```
import UIKit

open class PasscodeLockPresenter {

    fileprivate var mainWindow: UIWindow?

    fileprivate lazy var passcodeLockWindow: UIWindow = {

        let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        window.windowLevel = 0
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return window
    }()

    fileprivate let passcodeConfiguration: PasscodeLockConfigurationType
    open var isPasscodePresented = false
    open let passcodeLockVC: PasscodeLockViewController

    public init(mainWindow window: UIWindow?, configuration: PasscodeLockConfigurationType, viewController: PasscodeLockViewController) {

        mainWindow = window
        mainWindow?.windowLevel = 1
        passcodeConfiguration = configuration

        passcodeLockVC = viewController
    }

    public convenience init(mainWindow window: UIWindow?, configuration: PasscodeLockConfigurationType) {

        let passcodeLockVC = PasscodeLockViewController(state: .enterPasscode, configuration: configuration)

        self.init(mainWindow: window, configuration: configuration, viewController: passcodeLockVC)
    }

    open func presentPasscodeLock() {

        guard passcodeConfiguration.repository.hasPasscode else { return }
        guard !isPasscodePresented else { return }

        isPasscodePresented = true

        passcodeLockWindow.windowLevel = 2
        passcodeLockWindow.isHidden = false

        mainWindow?.windowLevel = 1
        mainWindow?.endEditing(true)

        let passcodeLockVC = PasscodeLockViewController(state: .enterPasscode, configuration: passcodeConfiguration)
        let userDismissCompletionCallback = passcodeLockVC.dismissCompletionCallback

        passcodeLockVC.dismissCompletionCallback = { [weak self] in

            userDismissCompletionCallback?()

            self?.dismissPasscodeLock()
        }

        passcodeLockWindow.rootViewController = passcodeLockVC
    }

    open func dismissPasscodeLock(animated: Bool = true) {

        isPasscodePresented = false
        mainWindow?.windowLevel = 1
        mainWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        if animated {

            animatePasscodeLockDismissal()

        } else {

            passcodeLockWindow.windowLevel = 0
            passcodeLockWindow.rootViewController = nil
        }
    }

    internal func animatePasscodeLockDismissal() {

        UIView.animate(
            withDuration: 0.5,
            delay: 0,
            usingSpringWithDamping: 1,
            initialSpringVelocity: 0,
            options: UIViewAnimationOptions(),
            animations: { [weak self] in

                self?.passcodeLockWindow.alpha = 0
            },
            completion: { [weak self] _ in

                self?.passcodeLockWindow.windowLevel = 0
                self?.passcodeLockWindow.rootViewController = nil
                self?.passcodeLockWindow.alpha = 1
            }
        )
    }
}
```

**PasscodeLockViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

open class PasscodeLockViewController: UIViewController, PasscodeLockTypeDelegate {

    public enum LockState {
        case enterPasscode
        case setPasscode
        case changePasscode
        case removePasscode

        func getState() -> PasscodeLockStateType {

            switch self {
            case .enterPasscode: return EnterPasscodeState()
            case .setPasscode: return SetPasscodeState()
            case .changePasscode: return ChangePasscodeState()
            case .removePasscode: return EnterPasscodeState(allowCancellation: true)
            }
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet open weak var titleLabel: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet open weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet open var placeholders: [PasscodeSignPlaceholderView] = [PasscodeSignPlaceholderView]()
    @IBOutlet open weak var cancelButton: UIButton?
    @IBOutlet open weak var deleteSignButton: UIButton?
    @IBOutlet open weak var touchIDButton: UIButton?
    @IBOutlet open weak var placeholdersX: NSLayoutConstraint?

    open var successCallback: ((_ lock: PasscodeLockType) -> Void)?
    open var dismissCompletionCallback: (()->Void)?
    open var animateOnDismiss: Bool
    open var notificationCenter: NotificationCenter?

    internal let passcodeConfiguration: PasscodeLockConfigurationType
    internal let passcodeLock: PasscodeLockType
    internal var isPlaceholdersAnimationCompleted = true

    fileprivate var shouldTryToAuthenticateWithBiometrics = true

    // MARK: - Initializers

    public init(state: PasscodeLockStateType, configuration: PasscodeLockConfigurationType, animateOnDismiss: Bool = true) {

        self.animateOnDismiss = animateOnDismiss

        passcodeConfiguration = configuration
        passcodeLock = PasscodeLock(state: state, configuration: configuration)

        let nibName = "PasscodeLockView"
        let bundle: Bundle = bundleForResource(nibName, ofType: "nib")

        super.init(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)

        passcodeLock.delegate = self
        notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
    }

    public convenience init(state: LockState, configuration: PasscodeLockConfigurationType, animateOnDismiss: Bool = true) {

        self.init(state: state.getState(), configuration: configuration, animateOnDismiss: animateOnDismiss)
    }

    public required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    deinit {

        clearEvents()
    }

    // MARK: - View

    open override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        updatePasscodeView()
        deleteSignButton?.isEnabled = false

        setupEvents()
    }

    open override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        if shouldTryToAuthenticateWithBiometrics {

            authenticateWithBiometrics()
        }
    }

    internal func updatePasscodeView() {

        titleLabel?.text = passcodeLock.state.title
        descriptionLabel?.text = passcodeLock.state.description
        cancelButton?.isHidden = !passcodeLock.state.isCancellableAction
        touchIDButton?.isHidden = !passcodeLock.isTouchIDAllowed
    }

    // MARK: - Events

    fileprivate func setupEvents() {

        notificationCenter?.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(PasscodeLockViewController.appWillEnterForegroundHandler(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)
        notificationCenter?.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(PasscodeLockViewController.appDidEnterBackgroundHandler(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidEnterBackground, object: nil)
    }

    fileprivate func clearEvents() {

        notificationCenter?.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)
        notificationCenter?.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidEnterBackground, object: nil)
    }

    open func appWillEnterForegroundHandler(_ notification: Notification) {

        authenticateWithBiometrics()
    }

    open func appDidEnterBackgroundHandler(_ notification: Notification) {

        shouldTryToAuthenticateWithBiometrics = false
    }

    // MARK: - Actions

    @IBAction func passcodeSignButtonTap(_ sender: PasscodeSignButton) {

        guard isPlaceholdersAnimationCompleted else { return }

        passcodeLock.addSign(sender.passcodeSign)
    }

    @IBAction func cancelButtonTap(_ sender: UIButton) {

        dismissPasscodeLock(passcodeLock)
    }

    @IBAction func deleteSignButtonTap(_ sender: UIButton) {

        passcodeLock.removeSign()
    }

    @IBAction func touchIDButtonTap(_ sender: UIButton) {

        passcodeLock.authenticateWithBiometrics()
    }

    fileprivate func authenticateWithBiometrics() {

        if passcodeConfiguration.shouldRequestTouchIDImmediately && passcodeLock.isTouchIDAllowed {

            passcodeLock.authenticateWithBiometrics()
        }
    }

    internal func dismissPasscodeLock(_ lock: PasscodeLockType, completionHandler: (() -> Void)? = nil) {

        // if presented as modal
        if presentingViewController?.presentedViewController == self {

            dismiss(animated: animateOnDismiss, completion: { [weak self] _ in

                self?.dismissCompletionCallback?()

                completionHandler?()
            })

            return

        // if pushed in a navigation controller
        } else if navigationController != nil {

            navigationController?.popViewController(animated: animateOnDismiss)
        }

        dismissCompletionCallback?()

        completionHandler?()
    }

    // MARK: - Animations

    internal func animateWrongPassword() {

        deleteSignButton?.isEnabled = false
        isPlaceholdersAnimationCompleted = false

        animatePlaceholders(placeholders, toState: .error)

        placeholdersX?.constant = -40
        view.layoutIfNeeded()

        UIView.animate(
            withDuration: 0.5,
            delay: 0,
            usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2,
            initialSpringVelocity: 0,
            options: [],
            animations: {

                self.placeholdersX?.constant = 0
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            },
            completion: { completed in

                self.isPlaceholdersAnimationCompleted = true
                self.animatePlaceholders(self.placeholders, toState: .inactive)
        })
    }

    internal func animatePlaceholders(_ placeholders: [PasscodeSignPlaceholderView], toState state: PasscodeSignPlaceholderView.State) {

        for placeholder in placeholders {

            placeholder.animateState(state)
        }
    }

    fileprivate func animatePlacehodlerAtIndex(_ index: Int, toState state: PasscodeSignPlaceholderView.State) {

        guard index < placeholders.count && index >= 0 else { return }

        placeholders[index].animateState(state)
    }

    // MARK: - PasscodeLockDelegate

    open func passcodeLockDidSucceed(_ lock: PasscodeLockType) {

        deleteSignButton?.isEnabled = true
        animatePlaceholders(placeholders, toState: .inactive)
        dismissPasscodeLock(lock, completionHandler: { [weak self] _ in
            self?.successCallback?(lock)
        })
    }

    open func passcodeLockDidFail(_ lock: PasscodeLockType) {

        animateWrongPassword()
    }

    open func passcodeLockDidChangeState(_ lock: PasscodeLockType) {

        updatePasscodeView()
        animatePlaceholders(placeholders, toState: .inactive)
        deleteSignButton?.isEnabled = false
    }

    open func passcodeLock(_ lock: PasscodeLockType, addedSignAtIndex index: Int) {

        animatePlacehodlerAtIndex(index, toState: .active)
        deleteSignButton?.isEnabled = true
    }

    open func passcodeLock(_ lock: PasscodeLockType, removedSignAtIndex index: Int) {

        animatePlacehodlerAtIndex(index, toState: .inactive)

        if index == 0 {

            deleteSignButton?.isEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

**EnterPasscodeState.swift**

```
import Foundation

public let PasscodeLockIncorrectPasscodeNotification = "passcode.lock.incorrect.passcode.notification"

struct EnterPasscodeState: PasscodeLockStateType {

    let title: String
    let description: String
    let isCancellableAction: Bool
    var isTouchIDAllowed = true

    fileprivate var inccorectPasscodeAttempts = 0
    fileprivate var isNotificationSent = false

    init(allowCancellation: Bool = false) {

        isCancellableAction = allowCancellation
        title = localizedStringFor("PasscodeLockEnterTitle", comment: "Enter passcode title")
        description = localizedStringFor("PasscodeLockEnterDescription", comment: "Enter passcode description")
    }

    mutating func acceptPasscode(_ passcode: [String], fromLock lock: PasscodeLockType) {

        guard let currentPasscode = lock.repository.passcode else {
            return
        }

        if passcode == currentPasscode {

            lock.delegate?.passcodeLockDidSucceed(lock)

        } else {

            inccorectPasscodeAttempts += 1

            if inccorectPasscodeAttempts >= lock.configuration.maximumInccorectPasscodeAttempts {

                postNotification()
            }

            lock.delegate?.passcodeLockDidFail(lock)
        }
    }

    fileprivate mutating func postNotification() {

        guard !isNotificationSent else { return }

        let center = NotificationCenter.default

        center.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: PasscodeLockIncorrectPasscodeNotification), object: nil)

        isNotificationSent = true
    }
}
```

**PasscodeLock.swift**

```
import Foundation
import LocalAuthentication

open class PasscodeLock: PasscodeLockType {

    open weak var delegate: PasscodeLockTypeDelegate?
    open let configuration: PasscodeLockConfigurationType

    open var repository: PasscodeRepositoryType {
        return configuration.repository
    }

    open var state: PasscodeLockStateType {
        return lockState
    }

    open var isTouchIDAllowed: Bool {
        return isTouchIDEnabled() && configuration.isTouchIDAllowed && lockState.isTouchIDAllowed
    }

    fileprivate var lockState: PasscodeLockStateType
    fileprivate lazy var passcode = [String]()

    public init(state: PasscodeLockStateType, configuration: PasscodeLockConfigurationType) {

        precondition(configuration.passcodeLength > 0, "Passcode length sould be greather than zero.")

        self.lockState = state
        self.configuration = configuration
    }

    open func addSign(_ sign: String) {

        passcode.append(sign)
        delegate?.passcodeLock(self, addedSignAtIndex: passcode.count - 1)

        if passcode.count >= configuration.passcodeLength {

            lockState.acceptPasscode(passcode, fromLock: self)
            passcode.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)
        }
    }

    open func removeSign() {

        guard passcode.count > 0 else { return }

        passcode.removeLast()
        delegate?.passcodeLock(self, removedSignAtIndex: passcode.count)
    }

    open func changeStateTo(_ state: PasscodeLockStateType) {

        lockState = state
        delegate?.passcodeLockDidChangeState(self)
    }

    open func authenticateWithBiometrics() {

        guard isTouchIDAllowed else { return }

        let context = LAContext()
        let reason = NSLocalizedString("PasscodeLockTouchIDReason", comment: "TouchID authentication reason")

        context.localizedFallbackTitle = localizedStringFor("PasscodeLockTouchIDButton", comment: "TouchID authentication fallback button")

        context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reason) {
            success, error in

            self.handleTouchIDResult(success)
        }
    }

    fileprivate func handleTouchIDResult(_ success: Bool) {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            if success {

                self.delegate?.passcodeLockDidSucceed(self)
            }
        }
    }

    fileprivate func isTouchIDEnabled() -> Bool {

        let context = LAContext()

        return context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: nil)
    }
}
```

Thank you so much!

Also, i'm using this code on my tableviewcontroller to attempt to present the .xib lockscreen

```
var passcodeLockPresenter: PasscodeLockPresenter = {

            let configuration = PasscodeLockConfiguration()
            let presenter = PasscodeLockPresenter(mainWindow: self.view.window, configuration: configuration)

            return presenter
        }()
        passcodeLockPresenter.presentPasscodeLock()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried delegating back to your VC or using a completion block so your VC can handle the presentation? It's best practice to leverage the present(viewController:animated:) API.

Comment: Sorry for the bother, but i'm a novice in swift programming, how would I go about implementing that into my code? Thank you so much in advance